# How to show current value (from model) in binded dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My cshtml page includes `for each` loop and I would like to bind the values in html fields.

I have already tried the following:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Load_Type",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LoadType, "Select", new {@class = "form-control", value = "obj.Load_type"})
```

but binding values in dropdown with selected current value is not working:

```
    @model List<model>   
foreach (var obj in Model)
        {
@Html.DropDownList("Load_Type",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LoadType,"Select", new {@class ="form-control",})
        }
```

Comment: Adding @Html.DropDownList inside `foreach` will render n number of dropdownlist.
Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is set the value with jquery onpageready.

First, add a selectLoop class and `data_selected = obj.SelectedValue` in the html helper. SelectedValue refers to the property that we have to match.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Load_Type",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LoadType,"Select", new {@class ="form-control selectLoop", data_selected = obj.SelectedValue })
```

Then in your script, loop through .selectLoop and assign the selected value for each of the select list.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // loop through all those with selectLoop class
   $(".selectLoop").each(function(){

      // get the selected value and store to variable
      var selected = $(this).attr("data-selected");

      // loop through all the option inside the select
      $(this).find("option").each(function(){

         // check if the value attribute matches the selected variable
         if($(this).attr("value") == selected){

            // if match, assign the option's selected attribute to true
            $(this).attr("selected") = true;
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Let me know if it doesn't work, include the html output/render of your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `value = @obj.Load_type` instead of `value = "obj.Load_type"`

Answer (score 0):

SelectListItem has a property called '**Selected**' just set it as True for value which you want to make selected.

Controller

```
public class Default16Controller : Controller
{
    // GET: Default16
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = "Select",
                Value = ""

            },
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = "One",
                Value = "1",
                Selected = true // Setting Item as Selected
            },
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = "Two",
                Value = "2"
            }
        };

        ViewBag.LoadType = li;
        return View();
    }
}
```

View

```
@{
Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("Load_Type", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LoadType, "Select", new { @class = "form-control", value = "obj.Load_type" })
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Result

[image]